# Facebook like-box code does not display scrollbar in android as well as iphone device

Tags: javascript, iphone, android, html, facebook

I want to display facebook like-box in my app, on all the desktop browsers it's working right. When I open page on android and iphone device html scrollbar does not appear there. I am not getting what is the problem with web-kit browsers.
My code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
 <head>
  <title>facebook </title>
 </head>

 <body>
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/imoment" width="292" show_faces="true" stream="true" header="false"></fb:like-box> </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the HTML5 version of the fb:like instead.  That might make it more compliant with web-kit.